# MVC 5 configuration variables

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in my mvc application I need to load at startup some variables (configuration parameters) that will be accessible for all controller.

Variables are configuration key,value came from a table in database, one time at startup.

How I can load this variables?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you asking -- how to load them (read from the database), when to load them, or where to store them?

Comment: I need load at startup application. And use this in all controller. I need an Hashtable . I need to read it from database and then access to value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would set the variable's value on Application_Start(). I would then save the value to a Session variable so that it can be retrieved by the controller later.

```
    protected void Application_Start() {
        var foo = fooService.GetFoo();
        Session["Foo"] = foo;
    }
```

It can then be accessed from a controller like this:

```
    protected string Foo {
        get {
            return (string)Session["Foo"] ?? ""

        }
    }
```

To avoid duplication, you can create some base controller class that does this that is then implemented by all of your other controllers.